# What is the difference between a=a*7 and a *= 7

Tags: python, numpy

I have written the below codes to make 2 functions.
The only difference is the second line.(input_array *= 7 and input_array = input_array * 7)

But they gave completely different results. （The results are in the picture attached)
I wonder why is that and what's the diefference between the two second lines？

```
def array_times_seven(input_array):
    input_array *= 7

    return input_array

test_array = np.ones((5,5))

array_times_seven(test_array[3:,3:])

test_array

#-----------------------------------------------

def array_times_seven(input_array):
    input_array = input_array * 7

    return input_array

test_array = np.ones((5,5))

array_times_seven(test_array[3:,3:])

test_array
```

[Result for the 1st code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJNxU.png)

[result for the 2nd code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM0lw.png)

Comment: In your first example your function returns nothing.

Comment: The first mutates the input argument, so you see changes in both the return value (which you ignore) and the global variable.  The second assigns a new value to `input_array`, so you only see the changes in the return value.  So there's the issue of mutating array, but also the issue of what happens to an input variable when a new object is assigned to it.  The second applies to all arguments in a function.

Comment: Pay attention to what the 2 functions return.  And test the two actions outside of functions.  That should help separate several issues.